# Eloquent automatically selects unwanted columns upon eager-loading model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am converting an internal API from HTML (back-end) processing to JSON (using Knockout.js) processing on the client-side to load a bunch of entities (vehicles, in my case).

The thing is our database stores sensitive information that cannot be revelead in the API since someone could simply reverse engineer the request and gather them.

Therefore I am trying to select specifically for every relationship eager-load the columns I wish to publish in the API, however I am having issues at loading a model relationship because it seems like Eloquent automatically loads every column of the parent model whenever a relationship model is eager loaded.

Sounds like a mindfuck, I am aware, so I'll try to be more comprehensive.

Our database stores many `Contract`, and each of them has assigned a `Vehicle`.

A `Contract` has assigned an `User`.

A `Vehicle` has assigned many `Photo`.

So here's the current code structure:

```php
class Contract
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Vehicle');
    }
}

class Vehicle
{
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Photo', 'vehicle_id');
    }
}

class Photo
{
    [...]
}
```

Since I need to eager load every single relationship listed above and for each relationship a specific amount of columns, I need to do the following:

```php
[...]

$query = Contract::join('vehicles as vehicle', 'vehicle.id', '=', 'contract.vehicle_id')->select([
    'contract.id',
    'contract.price_current',
    'contract.vehicle_id',
    'contract.user_id',
    'contract.office_id'
]);

[...]

$query = $query->with(['vehicle' => function ($query) {
    $query->select([
        'id',
        'trademark',
        'model',
        'registration',
        'fuel',
        'kilometers',
        'horsepower',
        'cc',
        'owners_amount',
        'date_last_revision',
        'date_bollo_expiration',
        'bollo_price',
        'kilometers_last_tagliando'
    ]);
}]);

$query = $query->with(['vehicle.photos' => function ($query) {
    $query->select([
        'id',
        'vehicle_id',
        'order',
        'paths'
    ])->where('order', '<=', 0);
}]);

$query = $query->with(['user' => function ($query) {
    $query->select([
        'id',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'phone'
    ]);
}]);

$query = $query->with(['office' => function ($query) {
    $query->select([
        'id',
        'name'
    ]);
}]);

[...]

return $this->response->json([
    'error'           => false,
    'vehicles'        => $vehicles->getItems(),
    'pagination'      => [
        'currentPage' => (integer) $vehicles->getCurrentPage(),
        'lastPage'    => (integer) $vehicles->getLastPage(),
        'perPage'     => (integer) $vehicles->getPerPage(),
        'total'       => (integer) $vehicles->getTotal(),
        'from'        => (integer) $vehicles->getFrom(),
        'to'          => (integer) $vehicles->getTo(),
        'count'       => (integer) $vehicles->count()
    ],
    'banner'          => rand(0, 2),
    'filters'         => (count($input) > 4),
    'filtersHelpText' => generateSearchString($input)
]);
```

The issue is: if I do not eager load `vehicle.photos` relationship, columns are loaded properly. Otherwise, **every single column** of `Vehicle`'s model is loaded.

Here's some pictures so you can understand:

[image: Picture when vehicle.photos isn't eager-loaded.]

[image: Picture when vehicle.photos is eager-loaded.]

---

Note: some information have been removed from the pictures since they are sensitive information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `hidden` property on your models which is an array of column names you want to hide from being output.

```
protected $hidden = ['password'];
```

Comment: `$hidden` affects globally the application. Is there any way to choose hidden properties depending in which "part of the application" you are?

Comment: You should be able to create a setter for it which you can use before querying.